# updateAll method not saving the first record

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a main form where can be found a `DataGridView` connected to a binding source, and a second form where the user can enter new records to the `DataGridView` (and save the changes to an Access database).

Apparently, it works fine because DGV is refreshed and a new row is added. However, when I call `UpdateAll` method of `TableAdpapterManager`, the data is not sent to the DB.

Then a strange thing happens: If I try to add multiple records, the previous "added" record is sent to DB. (In other words: If I add 2 new records, only the first is sent, which means that the last record is always lost)

Main form code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    NovaPesquisa.ShowDialog(FilaDeEsperaBindingSource)
    GuardarFilaDeEspera()
End Sub

Public Sub GuardarFilaDeEspera()

    Me.Validate()
    FilaDeEsperaBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.QuaerereDataSet)
End Sub
```

I've looked for problems like this and found out that the returned value of the `UpdateAll` method is very important. In this case, on the first record the returned value is 0 and from that on it's 1 (because it's updating the previous record)

Second form code:

```
Private WithEvents myBindingSource As BindingSource

Public Overloads Sub ShowDialog(ByVal bindingsource As BindingSource)

    myBindingSource = bindingsource
    Me.ShowDialog()
End Sub

Private Sub btnConfirmar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnConfirmar.Click

    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(comboActividade.Text) And _
       String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(comboLocalização.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Formulário inválido.", "Quaerere", _
                         MessageBoxButtons.OK, _
                         MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    Else
        myBindingSource.AddNew()
        Me.Close()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub AddingNew_Handler(ByVal sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.AddingNewEventArgs) Handles myBindingSource.AddingNew

    Dim dataTableView As DataView = TryCast(myBindingSource.List, DataView)
    Dim row As DataRowView = dataTableView.AddNew()
    row(COLUNA_PAÍS) = comboPaís.Text
    row(COLUNA_ACTIVIDADE) = comboActividade.Text
    row(COLUNA_LOCALIZAÇÃO) = comboLocalização.Text
    row(COLUNA_ESTADO) = _PESQUISA_EM_ESPERA
    e.NewObject = row
End Sub
```

I've no idea why this is happening, if it saves data of a second record why wouldn't it add the first record too?

Does anyone sees what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Why C#?  This is VB.NET code.

Comment: C# and vb.net are very close languages, whom understands vb.net easily understands C#... I used that tag so that C# programmers could also help me out!

Comment: @RafaelGil It's similar in the sense that it uses .NET. You should tag .NET.

Comment: I would have thought your call to `FilaDeEsperaBindingSource.EndEdit` would be enough, but try adding `row.EndEdit` in `AddingNew_Handler`.

Comment: @SimonBelanger: Some people only read questions that match their tag preference. If you have C# as your favorite tag, and don't have .NET, you would have never seen this question in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to EndEdit on the DataGridView so as to have the last row get into the DataSet prior to the execution of the updateall.

Comment: didn't worked out... still the same problem...
Thanks anyway!

Comment: In that situation, I would get into debug mode and examine the DataTable containing my data prior to calling UpdateAll. That will confirm if the row is indeed in the DataTable. If not then you know that you have to concentrate your efforts around EndEdit or maybe move the focus to another row programatically.